# How to get a particluar field out of jsonobject(arrays) using kafka streaming java8

Tags: stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

Could you please resolve my doubt. I was able to get a field out of jsonObject `(a-->{"host":"mou","type":"kat"})` in my Kafka topic by making use of Kafka Streams, with the below code in Java8.

```java
KStream<String, String> sources = builder
    .stream(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde, "example")
    .map((k,v) -> new KeyValue<>(k, (String) v.path("a").toString()));

sources.foreach((w, c) -> System.out.println("word: ->"  + c));

sources.print("FETCHING FIELD VALUE");
```

But if my input is `{"type":"abc","name":"abc","a"[{"host":"mouni"}]}` I am getting serialization error. (Please send a POC regarding my issue.)

Comment: Is the input value JSON? I am not an expert on JSON.

Comment: Hai Yeah the input is json, as I mentioned above in the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

with the below lines of code.

```
 KStream<String, String> sources = builder.stream(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde, "example")

               .map((k,v) -> new KeyValue<>(k,  v.path("l").path(0).path("a").toString()));
```